# how to access javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have this code for websocket. I want to call function broadcast for lRes. how can I do this?

```
var lRes = jwsc.logon('ws://localhost/WS', 'sendToWS', 'root', {

        // OnOpen callback
        OnOpen: function(aEvent) {
        },

        // broadcast callback
        broadcast: function() {
            var lRes = jwsc.broadcastText(
                "",
                lMsg    // broadcast this message
            );
        },

        // OnMessage callback
        OnMessage: function(aEvent, aToken) {
        },

        // OnClose callback
        OnClose: function(aEvent) {
        },
});
```

Comment: What particular problem are you facing with? You have `broadcast` signature in this class, what happens when you try calling it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Here I suggest you to call your function like :-

**lRes.broadcast();**

Comment: it should be an comment or better provide more details